# $query = "SELECT 'username', 'password' FROM 'userlist'

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

I get the following error when i run the code below

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''userlist' ORDER BY 'username'' at line 1

```
$query = "SELECT 'username', 'password' FROM 'userlist'";
mysql_query($query);

if ($query_run = mysql_query($query)) {
while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {
    echo $query_row('username').' --> '.$query_row('password').'<br>';
    }
} else {
    echo mysql_error();
```

}

Comment: Please see the big red box http://us2.php.net/mysql_query

Answer (score 3):

Only use single quotes for strings; not for columns and tables.

```
$sql = "SELECT username,password FROM users WHERE userId='string here'";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT username, password FROM `userlist`";
```

Not ' for table /column names.

Comment: Not sure if it is mysql version related but i saw similar example where column names were enclosed in quotes but worked. Anyways i removed single quotes and it worked, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, You have executed query two times `mysql_query($query);` , you can use one time.

```
     $query = "SELECT username, password FROM userlist ";
    if ($query_run = mysql_query($query)) {
        while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {
           echo $query_row['username'].' --> '.$query_row['password'].'<br>';
        }
    } else {
        echo mysql_error();

     }
```

instead of ,

```
 $query = "SELECT 'username', 'password' FROM 'userlist'";
```

Note: use mysqli_* functions or PDO instead of mysql_* functions(deprecated)